# Why is only the Fischer information a Riemannian metric?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, fisher-information

I recently discovered that the Fischer information induces a Riemannian metric on statistical manifolds. On discrete probability distributions the Fischer information is given by
$$\mathcal I_{j,k}(\theta)=\left\langle \sum_{j,k}\frac{\partial \ln p_i(\theta)}{\partial \theta_j}\frac{\partial \ln p_i(\theta)}{\partial \theta_k}\right\rangle=\sum_i\sum_{j,k}p_i(\theta)\frac{\partial \ln p_i(\theta)}{\partial \theta_j}\frac{\partial \ln p_i(\theta)}{\partial \theta_k}$$
where $p_i(\theta)$ is a discrete probability distribution over $i$, parametrized by a vector $\theta$ of parameters.

[It induces a metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information_metric) $h$ given by
$$h=\frac 1 4\sum_i\sum_{j,k}p_i(\theta)\frac{\partial \ln p_i(\theta)}{\partial \theta_j}\frac{\partial \ln p_i(\theta)}{\partial \theta_k}\mathrm d\theta_j\mathrm d\theta_k$$

My question is what makes this a Riemannian metric. Why not the metric $h=\sum_i\mathrm d p_i\mathrm d p_i$? Part of the confusion might stem from the fact that I do not understand the formal definition of a Riemannian metric completely.

---

Edit: after reading more carefully I seem to have misunderstood what I have read. I based this question on the following quote from this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information_metric

> The metric is interesting in several respects. By Chentsov’s theorem,
> the Fisher information metric on statistical models is the only
> Riemannian metric (up to rescaling) that is invariant under sufficient
> statistics.[1][2]

So for me to fully appreciate this fact, I have to do some more reading on sufficient statistics.

Comment: Good question. There are in fact infinitely many possible Riemannian metrics possible. Someone needs to explain why this one is the best.

Comment: @Deane Unclear to me how your comment is related to the question. The question appears to be "Why is x a Riemannian metric". Your comment seems to be "Why is x the best Riemannian metric". The answer to the former is easy. The answer to your comment, I cannot give.

Comment: @QuaereVerum i think you missed "only" in the post title

Comment: Reading the question more carefully, I see that the OP asks: Why not the metric $h=\sum_i\mathrm d p_i\mathrm d p_i$? Let me answer this: Each $p_i$ is a real number, so it is not clear what is meant by $dp_i$. If we interpret $p_i$ as a constant function, then $dp_i = 0$.

Comment: @user3716267 No, I did not. I just chose to ignore it because it's not true that only the Fischer metric is a Riemannian metric. The actual question just seems to ask what makes x a Riemannian metric.

Comment: I don’t think it hurts to ask if anyone can give a brief explanation of what a sufficient statistic is and roughly what the idea behind Chentsov’s Theorem is. I found this theorem too but did not read about it clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fisher information metric is, as you say, a Riemannian metric defined on a finite-dimensional family of discrete probability distributions. If it is a $k$-dimensional family of distributions, it should be viewed as a $k$-dimensional smooth manifold $M$, where each point $P$ in the manifold is a discrete probability distribution, i.e.,
$$ P = (p_1, \dots, p_N), $$ where
\begin{align*}
p_1, \dots, p_N &> 0\\
p_1+\cdots + p_N &= 1.
\end{align*}

A $k$-dimensional parameterization of all or part of the family is equivalent to a coordinate chart on the manifold $M$.
More precisely, if we denote the parameter (coordinates) by $\theta = (\theta^1, \dots, \theta^k) \in U$, where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$. A parameterization (coordinate map) is a smooth injective immersion $\Phi: U \rightarrow M$. $\Phi$ can be written as
$$ \Phi(\theta) = (p_1(\theta), \dots, p_N(\theta)). $$
The partial derivatives
$$ \partial_i\Phi(\theta) = \left(\frac{\partial p_1}{\partial\theta^i}, \dots, \frac{\partial p_N}{\partial\theta^i}\right) $$
comprise a basis of the tangent space at each $\Phi(\theta)$.

A Riemannian metric is an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ defined on each tangent space $T_PM$ that depends smoothly on the parameter (coordinates) $\theta$. Given the coordinates, a Riemannian metric is uniquely determined by the positive definie symmetric matrix whose components are
$$
g_{jk} = \left\langle \frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial \theta^j},\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \theta^k}\right\rangle.
$$
There are infinitely many possible choices for which inner product to use.
Two possible inner products are
$$
\left\langle \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \theta^j},\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \theta^k}\right\rangle
= \sum_{i=1} \frac{\partial p_i}{\partial \theta^j}\frac{\partial p_i}{\partial \theta^k}
$$
and the one that defines the Fisher information metric
$$
\left\langle \frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \theta^j},\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial \theta^k}\right\rangle
= \sum_{i=1} p_i^{-1}\frac{\partial \ln p_i}{\partial \theta^j}\frac{\partial \ln p_i}{\partial \theta^k}
$$
What I do not recall is why the Fisher information metric is more useful or natural than other possible choices.

Comment: The Fisher information metric is more useful or natural than other possible choices because by Chentsov’s theorem, the Fisher information metric on statistical models is the only Riemannian metric (up to rescaling) that is invariant under sufficient statistics

Comment: I have slightly misunderstood the question (as seen in my edit), so this doesn't answer the question I had in mind but since it does answer the question I asked in the title I will accept this

Comment: You don’t have to accept anything and you can change your mind later.